# Determine Network IP when given an IP and subnet mask

Tags: python, networking, ip, mask

In Python, if I have an IP address and a subnet mask as string, how do I determine the network IP?

i.e. IP = 10.0.0.20, mask = 255.255.255.0 would result in a network IP of 10.0.0.0

Comment: Simply `AND` the address with the mask to get the network. It works for IPv6, too.

Comment: Are these strings?

Comment: Never try to manipulate IP addresses as strings. That is a recipe for failure. IP addresses are binary numbers.

Comment: @RonMaupin, if you need to interface with users, they are going to enter the addresses as strings.

Comment: @StephenRauch, yes, but you never manipulate IP addresses in strings. You must use something that uses them as binary numbers. People that try to manipulate IP addresses as strings will inevitably have a problem.

Comment: @RonMaupin, agreed, the library I posted in the answer does any math the correct way.

Comment: `subnet = '.'.join([str(int(octet) & int(masked)) for octet, masked in zip(ip.split('.'), mask.split('.'))])` simple one-liner without third-party libs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module [ipcalc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipcalc) makes quick work of working with ip addresses as string:

#### Code:

```
import ipcalc

addr = ipcalc.IP('10.0.0.20', mask='255.255.255.0')
network_with_cidr = str(addr.guess_network())
bare_network = network_with_cidr.split('/')[0]

print(addr, network_with_cidr, bare_network)
```

#### Results:

```
IP('10.0.0.20/24') '10.0.0.0/24' '10.0.0.0'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't control the machine hosting the code, and ipcalc is not available to import. I have to do it the 'hard' way.

Comment: Most libraries are python.  You can simply deploy the library the same way you deploy your code....

Answer (score 11):

You can use the built-in [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) library:

```
import ipaddress
network = ipaddress.IPv4Network('10.0.0.20/255.255.255.0', strict=False)
print(network.network_address)
```

Result:

```
10.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I should probably post what I did.. It works for my purpose:

```
# Return the network of an IP and mask
def network(ip,mask):

    network = ''

    iOctets = ip.split('.')
    mOctets = mask.split('.')

    network = str( int( iOctets[0] ) & int(mOctets[0] ) ) + '.'
    network += str( int( iOctets[1] ) & int(mOctets[1] ) ) + '.'
    network += str( int( iOctets[2] ) & int(mOctets[2] ) ) + '.'
    network += str( int( iOctets[3] ) & int(mOctets[3] ) )

    return network
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ipaddress
network_address = ipaddress.ip_network('1000::5665/96', strict=False).network_address
#works for both ipv4 and ipv6
print(network_address)
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.